# Why is my repaint method not repainting?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, repaint

I am not sure why, but for some reason my `repaint` method is not working. I know that the movement is correctly working because I also have `println();` statements to help me check. I am not sure if it because of how I am painting my character onto the `JPanel`, or if it is because I am using a `BufferedImage` (I don't see why this would be the problem, but just a guess). Here is the code for where it is supposed to update (this is only the one to move up, the others are the same):

```
public class MazeController implements KeyListener {
MazeModel model;
MazePanel panel;
Maze maze = new Maze();

public MazeController(MazePanel panel, MazeModel model){
    this.panel = panel;
    this.model = model;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ //all of the different movement keys
    switch(e.getKeyCode()){ //get the Player's key press
    //UP
    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        model.setPreviousY(model.getPlayerX()); //keeps the old y coordinate just incase of collision
        model.moveUP(model.getPlayerY()); //moves up based on the Player's y coordinate
        maze.collisionChecker(model.getPlayerX(), model.getPlayerY());
        //after checking
        if(maze.getCollision() != true){
            System.out.println("You move up!"); //console output
            panel.repaint(); //moving the image only if it is a valid move
        }
        else if(maze.getCollision() == true){
            System.out.println("Illegal move, there is a wall!");
            model.setPlayerY(model.getPreviousY()); //resets there coordinate
            maze.setCollision(false); //resets the collision
        }

        System.out.println("Your current coordinates are: " + model.getPlayerX() + ", " + model.getPlayerY()); //checking coordinates
        break;
```

Here is the main paint method in the MazePanel class:

```
    public MazePanel(){ //constructor
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500)); //map size
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY); //ground color
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    maze.paintWall(g); //creates the walls
    p.playerPaint(g);
    e.paintEnemy(g);
}
```

I am trying to get `p.playerPaint(g);` to correctly repaint when the player tries to move. Again I know that the KeyEvents are working because I am able to see in my println(); statements state that it is correctly taking the directional movement for the x and y coordinates.

Player paint method:

```
class Player extends Entity{ //inheritance
Image i = new Image();
MazeModel model = new MazeModel();
//image = i.getPlayer();
private BufferedImage image = i.getPlayer();

public void setPlayerStart(int x, int y){
    model.setPlayerX(x); //sets the starting x position of the player's image
    model.setPlayerY(y); //sets the starting y position of the player's image
    System.out.println("Your current coordinates are " + model.getPlayerX() + ", " + model.getPlayerY());
}

public void playerPaint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, model.getPlayerX(), model.getPlayerY(), null); //creates the user
    System.out.println("Your current coordinates are " + model.getPlayerX() + ", " + model.getPlayerY());
}
}
```

Class that adds the controller:

```
public class MazeView extends JFrame { //FlowLayout
private MazePanel panel;
private MazeModel model;
private MazeController controller;

MazeView(){ //creating the JFrame and JPanel
    panel = new MazePanel();
    model = new MazeModel();
    controller = new MazeController(panel, model);

    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //non null FlowLayout
    addKeyListener(controller);
    add(panel);
    this.pack();
    this.setTitle("Maze game by Tyler Webster");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments to the question it can be seen **the problem is not with the `repaint` method** but with the instances of the `MazeModel` class that are being referred while changing the coordinates of the player and the one being referred while repainting the `player`.

The main problem is that a new instance `MazeModel` is initialised before initialisation of the `MazeController` in the `MazeView` constructor. Also another new instance of `MazeModel` is initialised in the `Player` class's constructor.

To over come this problem I would suggest that you pass the model as the parameter to the view's constructor. What I mean to say the constructor for `Player` should be :

```
public Player(MazeModel model){
    this.model = model;
    //rest of the constructor.
}
```

And the constructor `MazeView` should be:

```
public MazeView(MazeModel model){
    p = new Player(model);
    //all the other code
}
```

And `MazeView` constructor should be changed to:

```
MazeView(){ //creating the JFrame and JPanel
    model = new MazeModel();
    panel = new MazePanel(model);
    controller = new MazeController(panel, model);
}
```

This I hope should solve your problems.

Comment: You are brilliant thank you soooo much. My player finally moves! It makes sense to me now why it was not working. After I while I realized that they were not using the same MazeModel instance, however up until you helped me I had no idea of how I was to accomplish it. Thank you so much for all the time you put into helping me fix this!